# Logical operations on matrices columns.

Tags: matlab, matrix, logical-operators

Let say that I have 1 matrix with numbers (0,1). How can i create new matrix that is the result of a logical operation among the columns?

eg. A =

```
       0     0     0     1     0
       1     1     1     1     1
       0     1     1     0     0
       0     0     0     0     1
       1     0     0     1     0
       1     1     1     1     1

 If all elements of **rows** are equal to 1 - 1, if not - 0.
```

(like **AND** operation)

```
Ans=   0
       1
       0
       0
       0
       1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/all.html. For your case - `all(A,2)`

Comment: @Divakar, I suggest you post that as an answer before someone else does it =)

Comment: @RobertP. I always wondered that if OP's case is solved by the comments themselves, then why do we still need an answer?

Comment: @Divakar, I'm not sure if this is an official policy, but IMHO it should be. On the front page, the question will appear to be unanswered, while in fact it is answered. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your problem this would work -

```
all(A,2)
```

If you were looking to set elements based on the columnwise data in A, you would do this -

```
all(A,1)
```

More info on [`all`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/all.html), must serve you well.

Comment: +1 (This is why you make it an answer). @user3455066 Note that there is also the [`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) operation.

Comment: Thanks again. Divakar, I accept ur suggestion.Before i was posted, i find the answer.I think that i have wrong keyword.Anyway Thank you so much.